# ZeroCliboard not working on FF 17 upwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I am using ZeroClipboard version 1.0.7 on my webpage. 
The current stage is that it works perfectly on Chrome, IE and Firefox up to version 16.2.

When i tried ZeroClipboard on Firefox 17 i noticed that the plugin was not working anymore.

I upgraded to ZeroClipboard to 1.1.7 but now my script does not seem to work at all.
I get a **TypeError: element is undefined** on line 53 in file ZeroClipboard.js .

I could not figure out what i am not doing correctly and the element is never set.

Here is a part of my implementation

```
$(this).mouseover( function() {

        ZeroClipboard.setDefaults( { moviePath: '/script/ZeroClipboard.swf' } );
        clip = new ZeroClipboard();
        clip.setHandCursor( true ); 

    } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero Clipboard isn't maintained anymore , why not use http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/ . 
Its built on zero clipboard and maintained well.

Comment: i got some extra code that is based on zeroclipboard and it will take me extra time to make those changes again on the new script. I just also noticed that the ZeroClipboard.swf  is not available on the homepage for download.

Comment: Which version of zeroClipboard are you using ? .Do you have a fiddle which reproduces the issue ?

Comment: now i have put the latest version of Zeroclipboard, that is 1.1.7 . I am not sure if i can create a jsfiddle that easy. It's an enterprise application. I can give it a try maybe.

Comment: @Stephan why not try the master branch ? https://raw.github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard/master/ZeroClipboard.js

Can u create a fiddle ? for me its works well in firefox without issues

Comment: I tried to create a jsfiddle but its becoming rather complicated to make all those changes to match to my current implementation. In the end i believe i will save more time changing the implementation than completing the jsfiddle i started. I might probably give zClip a try.

Comment: I finally gave up with Zeroclipboard and added zClip. It works fine, its just that it takes a long time to load when i got something like 100 copy buttons on my page.  Any solution on this? With Zeroclipboard the page was loading relative fast. Right now i use an implementation like this: $('div button').each(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

I gave up with the zeroclipboard and went for the zClip finally.

There are some drawbacks but seems to work without any problems.